# which API to use the paypal adaptive module?

Tags: php, paypal

I purchased a PayPal Adaptive module, to make it work I have to enter the LIVE APP ID that was given to me when I activated the application on the PayPal site?
Or should I use the API that I create through my paypal account?

Answer (score 0):

For Adaptive you need your API credentials and your App ID.

Comment: Where can I find the number of my APP ID?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but in case it comes in handy for anyone in the future, you'll need to login to your developers account and click classic APIs